# Reading Entire Cells in excel sheet by checking for EOF

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

How to read a excel worksheet(Entire Cells) without specifying any range of columns by just checking for EOF, and than putting all the results dynamically into MS Access using VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Cells` property of `Worksheet` class and iterate until you will find your EOT condition of choice, eg. empty cell.

Something like this:

```
Dim w As Worksheet: Set w = ActiveSheet
Dim r As Long: r = 1
Dim vSQL As String

Do While w.Cells(r, 1).Text <> ""
    vSQL = "INSERT INTO MyTable1(Col1) VALUES(" & w.Cells(r,1).Text & ")" 
    yourFavoriteMethodToInvokeSQL vSQL

    r = r + 1
Loop
```

Comment: That finds the first blank cell in column 1 - which may be very different to the last used cell in column 1.

Comment: thanks, Radek i am a newbie to VB i am not able to understand the whole program what is this  yourFavoriteMethodToInvokeSQL vSQL that you asked to invoke and will it do for both numeric and text values?